# netbeans 8 aspectj perf4j and maven

Tags: maven, aspectj, perf4j

I'm looking into adding perf4j using aspectj compile time weaving.

I'm not familiar at all with aspectj but standard perf4j stopwatch was simple enough to get running using maven. I'd like now to take the next step and use @Profile annotations on the methods I want to monitor.

Problem is I'm struggling to find a tutorial that shows how to set this up using Netbeans and maven.

I need the weaving to take place during the build, examples I've found have used arc at the command line.

Comment: A little correction: If you need weaving to take place during the build, we are talking about compile-time weaving, not LTW (load-time weaving).

Comment: apologies good point - but the question still stands on how to accomplish this